# Randomly show attachment to a post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Here is my actual code :

```
<?php
if (have_posts()) :
$c = 0; while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $c++;
if ( $c == 1) {
$style = "current first";
}
elseif ( $c == count( $posts ) ) {
$style = "last"; } /*
elseif ( $c == 2 ) {
$style = ""; }*/

else $style ='dispa';


$images =& get_children( array (
'post_parent' => $post->ID,
'post_type' => 'attachment'

));
foreach ( $images as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {

?><div <?php post_class($style) ?>id ="post_<?php echo $post->ID;?>"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'large' ); }

?><div <?php post_class('mezzanine ' . $style) ?>><?php $description = $attachment->post_content;
echo $description;
?></div></div><?php
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
else :
echo wpautop( 'Sorry, no posts were found' );
endif;
?>
```

The result of this is to show the attachement image that is directly attached to the current post in a div. The description of the current post attachment is retrieved into another div (#mezzanine).
I want to show the post attachment in a random order but when i use 'orderby' => 'rand' there is no change in the order.
Does anyone see where is could come from?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `rand` like this

```
'orderby' => 'rand()'
```

May be it work for you

```
$query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_parent' => $post->ID ) ); 
$key = array_rand($query->posts, 1);

echo wp_get_attachment_image($query->posts[$key]->ID, 'medium');
```

Comment: there is a difference between getting 'post_type' => 'attachment' (all files that are in media library) and getting attachments linked to a every post. this is my issue..

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the answer?
http://php.quicoto.com/how-to-get-random-post-attachments-wordpress/

I'm about to test it myself.